# Help with a geometrical problem on ellipses

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Let $E$ the ecllipse, with center $O = (0,0)$, focus $F=(4,0)$ and vertex $V=(5, 0)$. Let $N$ be a point on the ellipse $E$, and let $Q$ be the orthogonal projection of $N$ onto the y-axis. Find the coordinates of the intersection of lines $ON$ and $QV$.

Excuse me first, I'm writing from a cellphone. I find $E$, $Q$ is $(0,y)$ and $N=(x, y)$. Then i found the intersection between the two lines, but I didn't get anything. Any help?

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have written the coordinates of two points on each line. From the coordinates of two points you can determine the equation of the line. From the equations of two lines you can determine the coordinates of their point of intersection. So when you say you found the intersection between the two lines, do you mean you found it like way $x$ is "found" in [the figure in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18354/69573)?

Comment: It seems to be a parabola having $\bigg(\dfrac52~,~0\bigg)$ as vertex, and passing through $(0,\,\pm\,3).$

Answer (score 0):

HINTS

Y would say:

The parametric equation of E:  $\displaystyle \quad x = 5\cos t,\quad y = 3 \sin t$

$\Rightarrow$ the koordinates of points $\displaystyle \quad N(5\cos t, 3\sin t), \quad Q(0,3\sin t)$

$\Rightarrow$ the equations of the lines  $\displaystyle \quad ON: y = \frac{3}{5}\tan t\cdot x, \quad QV: \frac{x}{5}+\frac{y}{3\sin t}=1$

$\Rightarrow$ the coordinates of the intersection of lines ON and QV $\equiv$ the parametric equation of the locus:

$\displaystyle \quad x = \frac{5}{2}(1-\tan^2\frac{t}{2}), \quad y = 3\tan \frac{t}{2}$

$\Rightarrow$ the equation of the locus in Cartesian coordinates:

$\displaystyle \quad y^2=3.6(2.5-x)$